# Angle of intersection between vectors intersecting at origin, use of r(0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

[image]

In this problem, as far as using t = 0, r(0), is that because of it being at the origin that zero is used? Or are they just picking that for some other reason?

Comment: `t = 0, r(0), is that because of it being at the origin` Yes, *the origin* is $t=0$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Figured that was most likely it, but wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything before moving on.